# Confused about configuring django-avatar for storing avatar

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Edit: Some random edits seem to do the work, but I don't understand how.

I have just "installed"  the app django-avatar into my django project. (currently, it is under development, so I am using the server which comes with django)

However. after I upload an avatar, neither can I find the avatar in any folder, nor is it being displayed. I am new to django, and python, so I don't know what to do, or which part of my code to post. I am completely clueless. I have set up a url, at which static files are server(via django.views.static.serve)

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

(settings is imported)

However. I feel this is wrong. I would like some guiding.

Media/Static related settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'd:/a4m/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (('d:/a4m/static/'),)
```

As for templates, I am just using the ones which django-avatar provides.

Comment: Add your settings related to anything media/static. It would be helpful as well to see the code in your template where you're trying to load the image.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Added whatever you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't add your project's static directory to `STATICFILES_DIRS`. You shouldn't be manually putting anything in that directory, so there's no reason to serve it in development (which is why Django doesn't by default). Also, I don't think it's related to this issue, but `STATIC_ROOT` needs a real value, which should be in your case:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'd:/a4m/static/'
```

That said, two things from looking at the django-avatar source:

1. It uses a setting named `AVATAR_STORAGE_DIR`, so you should probably define that if you haven't. It seems the following would be sensible:

   ```
   AVATAR_STORAGE_DIR = MEDIA_ROOT + 'avatars/'
   ```
2. If, for whatever reason, the avatar can't be written to the filesystem, django-avatar returns silently. So, I would check things like permissions to ensure that Django will have no problems writing to any directory under `AVATAR_STORAGE_DIR`.

Hopefully, that will be enough to get you a further in debugging this issue.